# Open Wireless network - Authentication required notification

Tags: android, authentication, networking, wifi, wireless

I wonder how Android determines when you connect to an open network whether you need to authenticate in your browser or not for the internet connection to be established.

Does it just check if it can reach the WAN by pinging some server or does it query the default gateway address and checks the reply for some kind of information that hints authentication?

I'm curious how this works but I haven't been able to find an answer. Your thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Android OS is just another Linux distro, hence it works like in any Linux. The rules for connecting to a wireless are independent from the OS, and regulated by the international standard IEEE_802.11. You will find tons of info, just Google it. The connection to a wireless network is done by a special deamon in Linux, called of course usually "network manager". The connection process is too complex to explain here, but you can find everywhere on Google or Wikipedia.